# Android animation width shape

Tags: android, animation, line, shapes

I want create a simple xml animation.

The animation will create a line that is wide 0px at t1 and screen width to the t2.

My Code.

line_dashed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line"> 

    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#000000"
        android:dashWidth="10dp"
        android:dashGap="5dp" />

</shape>
```

main.xml

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/lineDashed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/line_dashed" />
```